# Turning node.js mysql array into json string

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, json, node.js

I am using Node.js mysql and want to convert the result of MySQL query into a json string. Below is my code;

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'hkh'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * FROM hkh.monthly_XXX;', function (err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  //console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(rows);
  console.log('The solution is: ', jsonString);
});

connection.end();
```

Is there something wrong with using `jsonString = JSON.stringify(rows);`? When I copy and paste the result to notepad++, the json viewer says it is not a properly formatted json string.

Are there other methods to convert to a json string besides `jsonString = JSON.stringify(rows);`?

`jsonString` looks something like this;

```
"[{"id":1,"date_transacted":"1998-05-31T16:00:00.000Z","YYill_1_year_XX":2.6,"YYond_2_year_XX":3.15,"YYond_5_year_XX":3.94,"YYond_10_year_XX":5.3},{"id":2,"date_transacted":"1998-06-30T16:00:00.000Z","YYill_1_year_XX":3.2,"YYond_2_year_XX":3.58,"YYond_5_year_XX":4.04,"YYond_10_year_XX":5.43}]"
```

EDIT: Apologies to everyone who helped. The original code works fine. The mistake is due to  problems in the Notepad++ plugin and careless copy and paste.

Comment: Did you copy `The solution is: ` as well?

Comment: haha. No. That would be really dumb.

Comment: I didn't mean to say anything like that. Sorry :) Can you show a sample result?

Comment: THe \ in the sample result has been removed. They should not be there.

Comment: Hmmm, it looks a valid JSON string to me. I couldn't see any mistake in that.

Comment: @thefourtheye, you're right. It must be some careless mistake of mine. Let me examine closely.

Comment: if those outer quotes exist in actual response then it's not really json ... what's inside the quotes is though

Comment: Maybe you are copying the quotes `"`, because that is a valid json.